# How to read source code using git?

Tags: git

I downloaded source code from github. Now i want to read the program though out the initial commits to the last one step by step. Is it possible to read ver.1 first then read ver.2 and so on.. using git ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `git log` to get the list of commits. If you actually want to read the complete code at each revision you can pass the hash to `git checkout` to checkout that revision and poke around; if you just want to see the changes you can use `git show`. I recommend using a client for the latter case though, like [tig](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/), which will let you step through each commit easily and see the changes:

[image: Screenshot of tig]

Comment: Of course if you're one of those heretics who likes windows and clicking with the mouse, there's `gitk`.

Comment: @Jefromi Yeah, there's tons of clients; I like [gitg](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gitg/) personally

Answer (score 0):

If it's actually source code and not, say, fiction, it might be more informative to just look at the latest version, and if you see anything weird or unusual, use `git blame` (or if you're a heretic like me, `git gui blame`) to see which commit that line of code was added/changed in, which in turn might give you a hint of why it was written that way. Or if you want to know what all was changed between version X and version Y, you could do `git log X...Y`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the Git GUI.

Right click inside the repo, click 《Git GUI Here》, then click 《Repository》, then select 《Visualize All Branch History》.

RESET TO THE SPECIFIED VERSION

[image]

LOOK OVER NEARBY VERSION

[image]